# $compile nested directive from within another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

TL;DR; [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5HnTT/).

I want to use two directives (`kmOuter` and `kmInner`) as nested directives:

```
<div km-outer>
    <div km-inner></div>
    <div km-inner></div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

So I declared them as follows. Please note that inner directive requires outer's controller:

```
app.directive('kmOuter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        scope: null,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            this.childAdded = function () {
                console.log('Child added.');
            };
        }
    };
});

app.directive('kmInner', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        require: '^kmOuter',
        template: '<div>Lorem ipsum</div>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, kmOuterController) {
            kmOuterController.childAdded();
        }
    };
});
```

That works just fine (`.childAdded()` is being called, among others). Now, I want to dynamically insert new instances of inner directive. This action is being triggered from some third, unrelated directive:

```
app.directive('kmChildAdder', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        scope: {
            target: '@kmChildAdder'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            console.log(scope);
            var target = document.querySelector(scope.target);

            angular.element(elem[0]).bind('click', function () {
                // Error is here
                var newInner = $compile('<div km-inner></div>')(scope)[0];
                target.appendChild(newInner);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Used like this:

```
<button km-child-adder="[km-outer]">Add child</button>
```

But it breaks with the following message:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'kmOuter', required by directive 'kmInner', 
can't be found!
```

`.childAdded()` isn't called anymore.

How can I fix this? Or maybe this design is itself broken and I should reorganise my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I made it, borrowing from @Mobin Skariya's answer.

Key was to `$compile` only the inserted element, not all elements:

```
link: function (scope, elem) {
    var target = angular.element(document.querySelector(scope.target));

    angular.element(elem[0]).bind('click', function () {
        var newInner = angular.element('<div km-inner="param"/>');
        target.append(newInner);

        scope.$apply(function () {
            $compile(newInner)(scope);
        });
    });
}
```

I've prepared [jsFiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/kamituel/dqddH/) where third, unrelated directive inserts ad compiles inner directive with working, two-way data bindings - you will find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kamituel/dqddH/). Nice thing about it is that third directive (`kmChildAdder`) can insert inner directives taking bindings from multiple, separate controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Made some edits in your code. Code given in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mobinskariya/mDc2Z/1/) link

```
link: function (scope, elem) {
            console.log(scope);
            var target = document.querySelector(scope.target);
            angular.element(elem[0]).bind('click', function () {
                var newInner = '<div km-inner></div>';
                angular.element(target).append(newInner);
                $compile(target)(scope)
            });
        }
```

Check whether this is what you expect.

Comment: It's close, definitely an improvement, thanks. Problem is now it recompiles the whole `kmOuter` directive, so `.childAdded()` is being called n times per one child added (where n = number of children). I want it to be called only once per every new child. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry i didn't see that :)

Comment: Not a problem. I gave +1 anyway, as your idea could be useful. It's just not what I need in this case.

Comment: I've made it (see my answer) - key was to not compile the whole `target`, but rather only `angular.element("<div km-inner/>")` (also, to use `scope.$apply` for proper bindings). Thank you for an idea!